# How to calculate some data with python?

Tags: python, json, csv

I have JSON file. I have parsed it and I have extracted some data which are classes and code smells. Now I should calculate the number of smells on each class. I tried this with an example of code smells and it return for me the number of this smell in all the json file.
this is a part of the Json file beacause it's too long

```
  {
"methods": [
  {
    "parametersTypes": [
      "Bundle"
    ],
    "sourceFile": {
      "file": {
        "path": "/mnt/c/shortrain-master/app/src/main/java/com/nirhart/shortrain/MainActivity.java"
      }
    },
    "metricsValues": {
      "ParameterCount": 1.0,
      "NumberOfAccessedVariables": 9.0,
      "ChangingClasses": 0.0,
      "CouplingDispersion": 0.5,
      "MethodLinesOfCode": 21.0,
      "MaxNesting": 0.0,
      "CyclomaticComplexity": 1.0,
      "MaxCallChain": 2.0,
      "ChangingMethods": 0.0,
      "CouplingIntensity": 4.0
    },
    "fullyQualifiedName": "com.nirhart.shortrain.MainActivity.onCreate",
    "smells": []
  },
  {
    "parametersTypes": [],
    "sourceFile": {
      "file": {
        "path": "/mnt/c/shortrain-master/app/src/main/java/com/nirhart/shortrain/MainActivity.java"
      }
    },
    "metricsValues": {
      "ParameterCount": 0.0,
      "NumberOfAccessedVariables": 2.0,
      "ChangingClasses": 1.0,
      "CouplingDispersion": 0.0,
      "MethodLinesOfCode": 6.0,
      "MaxNesting": 0.0,
      "CyclomaticComplexity": 1.0,
      "MaxCallChain": 6.0,
      "ChangingMethods": 3.0,
      "CouplingIntensity": 0.0
    },
    "fullyQualifiedName": "com.nirhart.shortrain.MainActivity.finishActivity",
    "smells": [
      {
        "name": "MessageChain",
        "reason": "MAX_CALL_CHAIN = 6.0",
        "startingLine": 54,
        "endingLine": 66
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parametersTypes": [
      "View"
    ],
    "sourceFile": {
      "file": {
        "path": "/mnt/c/shortrain-master/app/src/main/java/com/nirhart/shortrain/MainActivity.java"
      }
    },
    "metricsValues": {
      "ParameterCount": 1.0,
      "NumberOfAccessedVariables": 4.0,
      "ChangingClasses": 0.0,
      "CouplingDispersion": 1.0,
      "MethodLinesOfCode": 6.0,
      "MaxNesting": 1.0,
      "CyclomaticComplexity": 3.0,
      "MaxCallChain": 1.0,
      "ChangingMethods": 0.0,
      "CouplingIntensity": 2.0
    },
    "fullyQualifiedName": "com.nirhart.shortrain.MainActivity.onClick",
    "smells": []
  },
  {
    "parametersTypes": [],
    "sourceFile": {
      "file": {
        "path": "/mnt/c/shortrain-master/app/src/main/java/com/nirhart/shortrain/MainActivity.java"
      }
    },
    "metricsValues": {
      "ParameterCount": 0.0,
      "NumberOfAccessedVariables": 0.0,
      "ChangingClasses": 0.0,
      "CouplingDispersion": 1.0,
      "MethodLinesOfCode": 3.0,
      "MaxNesting": 0.0,
      "CyclomaticComplexity": 1.0,
      "MaxCallChain": 1.0,
      "ChangingMethods": 0.0,
      "CouplingIntensity": 1.0
    },
    "fullyQualifiedName": "com.nirhart.shortrain.MainActivity.onBackPressed",
    "smells": []
  }
],
"sourceFile": {
  "file": {
    "path": "/mnt/c/shortrain-master/app/src/main/java/com/nirhart/shortrain/MainActivity.java"
  }
},
"metricsValues": {
  "ClassLinesOfCode": 40.0,
  "OverrideRatio": null,
  "WeighOfClass": 1.0,
  "LCOM2": 0.5,
  "TightClassCohesion": 0.0,
  "LCOM3": 0.6666666666666666,
  "NumberOfAccessorMethods": 0.0,
  "WeightedMethodCount": 6.0,
  "IsAbstract": 0.0,
  "PublicFieldCount": 0.0
},
"fullyQualifiedName": "com.nirhart.shortrain.MainActivity",
"smells": []
  },
```

]

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import json

all_smells=['LazyClass','ComplexClass','LongParameterList','FeatureEnvy','LongMethod','GodClass','MessageChain']

with open('/content/result_smells.json') as handle:
  dictdump = json.loads(handle.read())

my_map = {}

for elem in dictdump : 
  my_map[elem["fullyQualifiedName"]] = []
  #adding all class smells 
  for class_smell in elem["smells"] :
    my_map[elem["fullyQualifiedName"]].append(class_smell)


  #adding all methods smells  
  for method in  elem["methods"] : 
    for method_smell in method["smells"] : 
      my_map[elem["fullyQualifiedName"]].append(method_smell)

for elem in my_map : 
  print(elem)
  for smell in my_map[elem] : 
  print(smell["name"])
```

This is the result : the name of class and the smells on it

```
com.nirhart.shortrain.MainActivity
MessageChain
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.PathParser
ComplexClass
FeatureEnvy
LongParameterList
LongParameterList
LongMethod
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.PathPoint
LazyClass
LongParameterList
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.TrainPath
FeatureEnvy
com.nirhart.shortrain.rail.RailActionActivity
FeatureEnvy
LongMethod
com.nirhart.shortrain.rail.RailInfo
com.nirhart.shortrain.train.TrainActionActivity
ComplexClass
SpaghettiCode
LongMethod
LongMethod
IntensiveCoupling
```

I try to calculate the number of the MessageChain smell in `com.nirhart.shortrain.MainActivity` class which is one it return for me 5 which is the MessageChain smell in all the json file
this is my code:

```
x=0
for elem in my_map : 
  print(elem)
  for smell in my_map[elem] : 
    if smell["name"]=='MessageChain':
      x+=1
```

Then I need to put all results on a CSV to analyse it.
this is an exemple of csv file with one smell

[image]

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include an example of the JSON data you are reading, we could then use it to run your script. Also please show exactly how the output CSV file should look like.

Comment: I edited it  hope you can help me and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Python [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html?highlight=collections%20counter#collections.Counter) can be used to simplyfy counting the `smells`, and a [`csv.DictWriter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) can be used to then write the resulting dictionary holding all of the counts. For example:

```
from collections import Counter
import csv
import json

all_smells = ['LazyClass', 'ComplexClass', 'LongParameterList', 'FeatureEnvy', 'LongMethod', 'GodClass', 'MessageChain']
my_map = {}

with open('result_smells.json') as f_json:
    json_data = json.load(f_json)

for entry in json_data:
    my_map[entry["fullyQualifiedName"]] = []

    #adding all class smells 
    for class_smell in entry["smells"] :
        my_map[entry["fullyQualifiedName"]].append(class_smell)

    #adding all methods smells  
    for method in entry["methods"] : 
        for method_smell in method["smells"] : 
            my_map[entry["fullyQualifiedName"]].append(method_smell)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=["NameOfClass", *all_smells], extrasaction='ignore', restval='NaN')
    csv_output.writeheader()

    for elem in my_map : 
        smell_counts = Counter()

        for smell in my_map[elem] : 
            smell_counts[smell["name"]] += 1

        smell_counts['NameOfClass'] = elem
        csv_output.writerow(smell_counts)
```

Giving you an output CSV file looking like:

```
NameOfClass,LazyClass,ComplexClass,LongParameterList,FeatureEnvy,LongMethod,GodClass,MessageChain
com.nirhart.shortrain.MainActivity,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,1
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.PathParser,NaN,1,2,1,1,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.PathPoint,1,NaN,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.TrainPath,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.rail.RailActionActivity,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,1,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.rail.RailInfo,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.train.TrainActionActivity,NaN,1,1,1,2,NaN,2
com.nirhart.shortrain.train.TrainDirection,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.train.TrainView,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.tutorial.TutorialFragment,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.tutorial.TutorialFragment.OnNextSlideClicked,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.tutorial.TutorialViewPagerAdapter,1,NaN,NaN,1,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.utils.ShortcutsUtils,NaN,NaN,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,2
```

Comment: You would need to give me a link to a more realistic json file as this was tested on the data you gave. You could use a service like pastebin.